# Some issue with heroku scheduler

Tags: php, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I work with add-on heroku scheduler Advanced Scheduler. I created a php script which works in CLI mode and is launched like `php /app/crons/pushnotifications.php`.  In my Heroku plan I can run the script every 10 minutes, and in order to run it every minute I try to implement script restart every minute

```
$start = time();
while ((time() - $start) <= 9*60)
{
    $start_loop = time();
    something to do...
    sleep(max(0, 60-(time() - $start_loop)));
}
```

It looks like it does work fine but sometimes (once in two days this script crushed and I receive a letter on email "You are receiving this email because one of your scheduled tasks is failing to run properly").

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'd presume the failure is somewhere within the `something to do...` bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can add something like this to the end of your command:

```
php path/file.php || echo "fail"
```

This will block the webhook on the fail.
Yes, it's just a hack, but if everything works fine and you get such error messages, it will be useful for you.